# Is MySQL a Distributed Database by Design

Tags: mysql, database, distributed

Is MySQL a database that (1) can be configured via increasing the number of replicas (2) without losing the ability to be updated anywhere and stay in sync everywhere.

In other words, is MySQL distributed **by design** or is it something that lives on a single machine and if I want to scale horizontally, I would have to do manual work like implement sharding/consistent hashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is MySQL a Distributed Database by Design

No. MySQL is a *centralized* database by design.

> Is MySQL a database that (1) can be configured via increasing the number of replicas (2) without losing the ability to be updated anywhere and stay in sync everywhere.

Also no. MySQL replication generally depends on a master-slave architecture. Under this architecture, all writes must be applied through the (single) master, so there is no "ability to be updated everywhere". Multi-master architectures are possible, but only on a limited scale, and even then only with significant caveats.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can be used as a distributed database as per the MySQL documentation using [MySQL Cluster CGE](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/). This provides auto-partitioning and scalability. It also provides a distributed query engine.

Having said that, you will still have to do work to set it up properly. To my knowledge there is no DB out there that will just magically know how you want to optimally  distribute the data. Even databases that were designed from the ground up to be distributed will require some manual work to work optimally